# Lightbox Border Image Overlap

Tags: jquery, html, css, border, lightbox

Recently I have been working on this website page updating it's gallery using Lightbox. It seems to be working perfectly, however from time to time when opening or reloading the page and clicking on the images the enlarged image seems to overlap with the border as seen in the image below.

If there is a problem with my html or if it is just a bug with Lightbox then I would really appreciate it if you could let me know how to fix it or if there is anyway to avoid the problem.

If you need to see any more of my html or css then please let me know also.
Thanks very much!

https://38.media.tumblr.com/705e496cca9600e899fcb0260fb2dabc/tumblr_n94qyaVLo61sgfoz6o1_500.png

```
<div id="imgContainer">

    <div id="editorial1">
        <a href="Images/Editorial-8_lg.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title=""><img src="Images/thumb1.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We'll definitely need to see more code.

Comment: Sorry about that, obviously I'm using the jquery and lightbox files provided on the Lightbox website but here are download links to my html and css files:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/1282bwy1jwxuxvb/editorial.html
http://www.mediafire.com/download/z6d9yd1nb5xa7cu/gallery.css

Hope this helps.